# Definition of operators

Tags: c++, class, operators

I am trying to define some operators.

I do it according to this documentation:

http://courses.cms.caltech.edu/cs11/material/cpp/donnie/cpp-ops.html

Is there an operator that should be defined twice?

I think that it's the index operator. am I right? I defined it such as:

```
int operator [] (const int power) const{
    // here there is some code
}
```

Assuming I implement it correctly, what's about the operator that should have be defined twice?

Does it support the next things?

```
a[1] = 3;
cout << a[1]; // I defined the << operator
```

any help appreciated!

Comment: The second one would work, but the first would fail because you aren't returning a reference.

Comment: so I have to define it by: int& operator[] (const int power) const;

Comment: Yes, you should define another overload of the operator that returns `int&`.

Comment: Just a note re the suggestion *you should define another overload of the operator that returns int&* above - the version returning a reference shouldn't have const after the list of function arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think that it's the index operator. am I right?

Almost. It is called the *subscript operator*, and it must accept **one** single argument. Your operator accepts two, and that makes your code illegal.

> Does it support the next things?

Supposing you have a properly written `operator []` (without knowing some context from the logic of your application I cannot tell how to write one), then both the instructions you mention should be supported.

However, in order for this:

```
a[1] = 3;
```

To be legal (if a fundamental type is returned), `operator []` should return an lvalue reference - therefore, `int&` and not `int`. Of course, this means the object to which the lvalue reference is bound cannot be a local object or a temporary, because that would mean returning a *dangling* reference.

```
int& operator [] (const int power) { // <== The function cannot be "const" if you
// ^                                 //     are returning a non-const lvalue ref
                                     //     to a data member or element of a data
                                     //     member array
    // here there is some code
}
```

You may also want a `const` version of the subscript operator:

```
int operator [] (const int power) const {
// No need to use a int const&    ^^^^^
// here, that is basically the    This member function can be const, since it is
// same as returning an int by    neither modifying the object on which it is
// value                          invoked, nor returns any non-const lvalue ref
                                  to a data member or an element of data member
    // here there is some code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to have both a `const` and a non-`const` versions of the operator:

```
int operator[](int index) const { ... }
int& operator[](int index) { ... }
```

This will permit both usages given in your example. It will also permit the second usage even if `a` is `const`.

Comment: @AlonShmiel: they don't do the same.  The first one returns an int value which is presumably copied from the value at that index inside your object, but that copy has no ongoing connection to the container.  The second one typically grants the calling code read/write access to the int value deemed to be at that index inside the object - the calling code can write to this `x[i] = n;` and change affects the data in the object itself.  The second one is called only when the object is not const, to prevent modification of a const object.

Answer (score 1):

To support assignment there are two options

1. The indexing operator `[]` returns a reference
2. The indexing operator `[]` returns a proxy object that implements assignment

The first case is the simplest, but doesn't allow you to distinguish between read and write operations. The second method is a bit more complex but allows more control:

An example of approach (2) is the following

```
struct MyArray {
    std::vector<int> v;

    MyArray(int n) : v(n) {}

    struct ItemRef {
        MyArray& a;
        int index;

        ItemRef(MyArray& a, int index)
          : a(a), index(index)
        {}

        int operator=(int x) {
            printf("Writing to element %i\n", index);
            a.v[index] = x;
            return x;
        }

        operator int() {
            printf("Reading element %i\n", index);
            return a.v[index];
        }
    };

    ItemRef operator[](int index) {
        if (index < 0 || index >= int(v.size()))
            throw std::runtime_error("Invalid index");
        return ItemRef(*this, index);
    };
};
```